# Android webviews in os 4.1 and 4.2

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

When running web view in devices 4.1, 4.4 and above the webview work fine with good performance. but when running on device 4.2.2 the performance turn bad and very slow.

I know that android webview turned Chromium on devices os 4.4 and above rather then the native android browser and that explain why they work well in these devices. but why is the webview work well in 4.1? its suppose to be the same web view

My problem is the bad performance in the android 4.2.2. i tried all different things like turning off hardware acceleration (work but will not show html-5 components) setting render priority but none works. is there a way to improve performance?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately WebView on Android prior KitKat are buggy. It's possible that some bug were introduced in version 4.2.2 and they may also depends on specific device vendor (I had different behaviors with Samsung devices especially). Based on my experience, some issues could be resolved by turning off hardware acceleration, other using some workaround on Javascript\HTML\CSS part, but depends on the specific case.

Never tried using third part WebView like GeckoV[enter link description here](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mobile/GeckoView)iew or [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org)